# Spring Data JPA extracting limited fields from a model

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA and below is my Dto for AssetItem . Here in assetItemDocsCollection i am trying to fetch Collection . But i dont want all fields from AssetItemDocs . For example i dont want documentByte as this field will be huge . I just want all fields leaving this field , how can i do this in less code .

```java
public class AssetItemDto extends AbstractDto<Long> {

    private Collection<AssetItemDocs> assetItemDocsCollection;
}

public class AssetItemDocs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "document_byte")
    private byte[] documentByte;
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date creationDate;
    @JoinColumn(name = "asset_item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private AssetItem assetItemId;
}
```

Comment: create the AssetItemDto with the fields you want then use a mapper to convert entity to dto  then return a List<AssetItemDto> on the controller

Comment: What is the context of the `fetch` you are talking about? Do you have a web service that responds with one of these objects?

Answer (score 0):

**This is typically what [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) are made for: retrieving only part of the entity's attributes.** There are several ways to do it, but for instance:

Instead of having `AssetItemDocs` entities in the `Collection` of your DTO, create another DTO with all fields of `AssetItemDocs` that you want to fetch (that is all except `documentByte`). That DTO must have a constructor with all theses fields as parameters (type and name must match those declared in the entity).

Then in your repository, write a query method whose return type is a `Collection` of that DTO. If your query is derivable by its method name, it will work as is, but if your method is written using a JPQL query in a `@Query` annotation, you'll need to explicitly call the DTO constructor in the `select` cause with this kind of syntax: `SELECT new full.package.MyDTO(entity.attribute1, entity.attribute2) FROM MyEntity entity`.

Then you just have to include the `Collection` returned by the repository in your `AssetItemDto`.

NB: although it would be possible to make a projection using the same entity class instead of a new DTO, I personally think it's a bad practice to expose entity objects in a DTO.